# Create large correlation matrix with different correlation values

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to create a correlation matrix for 50 variables where different variables have different correlations.

In the perfect case when each variable has the same correlation I would use:

```
cor.table <- matrix(rep(0.8,2500),50,50)
diag(cor.table) <- 1
```

However, now I would like to have for example 40 variables with correlation `.6` and the remaining 10 with correlation `-.2`.

How can I set up such a table with the `matrix()` command?

For example:

```
      1     2     3     4     5

1     1   -0.2   0.6   0.6   0.6

2   -0.2    1    0.6  -0.2   0.6

3    0.6   0.6    1    0.6  -0.2

4    0.6  -0.2   0.6    1    0.6

5    0.6   0.6  -0.2   0.6    1
```

Comment: Simon, yes that's what I was looking for can you repost please?

Comment: I had to make it symmetric first - was missing a `t()` !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this? [with a 100 times smaller example!]...

```
cor.table <- matrix( c( rep(0.8,20) , rep( -0.8 , 5) ) , 5 , 5 )
diag(cor.table) <- 1

#  Make matrix symmetric - the 't()' is necessary for this
cor.table[ lower.tri(cor.table) ] <- t( cor.table )[ lower.tri( cor.table ) ]
cor.table
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  1.0  0.8  0.8  0.8 -0.8
[2,]  0.8  1.0  0.8  0.8 -0.8
[3,]  0.8  0.8  1.0  0.8 -0.8
[4,]  0.8  0.8  0.8  1.0 -0.8
[5,] -0.8 -0.8 -0.8 -0.8  1.0
```

to shuffle up where the negative correlations are just use random sampling. Replace the first line with this:

```
cor.table <- matrix( sample( c(0.6,-0.2) , 25 , prob = c( 0.8 , 0.2 ) , repl = TRUE ) , 5 , 5 )
```

The `prob` argument to `sample` tells us we expect to get `0.6` `80%` of the time and the negative correlation, `-0.2` only `20%` of the time. You can adjust these as you wish. Following the rest of the code to get...

```
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]  1.0  0.6 -0.2 -0.2  0.6
#[2,]  0.6  1.0  0.6  0.6 -0.2
#[3,] -0.2  0.6  1.0 -0.2  0.6
#[4,] -0.2  0.6 -0.2  1.0  0.6
#[5,]  0.6 -0.2  0.6  0.6  1.0
```

Comment: One minor thing. In this case it seems that all variables that are negatively correlated, are negatively correlated with variable 5. Is it possible to mix this up a little bit? so that not only variable 5 has negative correlations but those are actually randomly distributed in the matrix?

Comment: @user1984076 show a 5x5 (ish)size matrix showing an example of what you are after. I don't want to spend time making a solution that isn't right. Thanks!

Comment: @user1984076 yes this is quite do-able. Give me a few mintues - I'm just doing something else. I'll message when updated.

Comment: @user1984076 updated. I hope this is what you are looking for.